# rMBP Doesn't Wake Up From Sleep After Upgrading to ML

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

It is the second time that my rMBP doesn't wake up from sleep. The only application that I've recently installed are Alferd and BetterTouchTool - Could it have something to do with that?

In addition it happened twice only after long time sleep of like 8 hours - if I sleep the machine now and wake it after 2 minutes it wakes up perfectly.

Do you have any ideas what can cause this? In Lion I had no problems.

EDIT: Apple released the following update

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1559

hopefully this will fix the problem.

EDIT: Nope, didn't help.

EDIT: I freshly installed ML again, which fixed my problem. I have added an answer below, please read it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with Macbook Air 2011 - http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=1872401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally a solution that worked.

I formatted my partition and freshly installed ML, which fixed my wakening problems.
Here is a tutorial on how I freshly installed ML: 
[How To Fresh Install ML](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58363/how-to-fresh-install-ml)

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, unfortunately, but a report of the same problem with a MacBook air (mid 2012). It was running Lion without a glitch, but ever since I upgraded with ML, I can't wake it up from sleep (closed lid) when I try to use it back in the morning. To get control back over the machine, I need to do a SMC Reset (Left Shift - Option - Control + Power button at the same time) for a hard reset. I tried to install the SMC update mentioned in the EDIT, but the MBair refused to accept it. Still at a loss… 
I have unchecked the Power Nap feature to see if it would make a difference, but to no avail.

Comment: Sorry for not updating but I found the solution which works well for me. I formatted my partition and freshly installed ML, which fixed my wakening problems.